# Field validation in a Django form

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a Django form consisting of a email and name field. I want to validate the name to have more than 8 characters. I have used the following code. But it is not working.

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=SignUp
        fields=('email','name')
    def emailValidation(self):

        name=self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        if len(name) <=8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("name cannot be less than 8")
```

models.py

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField()
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    form=SignUpForm(request.POST or None)                                           
    if form.is_valid():                                             

        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        print instance.timestamp
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Are you certain the indentation in the form is the same as in your actual file?

Comment: i had messed it up completely..have corrected it now

Comment: What is the error you get? Also you do `if len(name) <=8:`, where did you declare variable `name`? Did you do `name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')` anywhere?

Comment: @fips  yeah.i edited it..actualy even with using  self.cleaned_data.get('name')  the form is getting saved successfully in the database when I use a name less than 8 characters.

Comment: Sounds your validation function is not called, debug it or write a print statement to verify that. It seems you are not using django's naming convention for that. `def clean(self):` or `def clean_<fieldname>(self):`. Place your code in there and make sure you extract the right field using `cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()` and raise an error if `len(cleaned_data.get("name")) <= 8`. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean

Comment: @fips  thanks..it is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In your SignUpForm, in the function emailValidation, you haven't returned 'name'. Also a major mistake is that you have to name the function clean_(field_name) and NOT emailValidation.
This should do it I guess:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=SignUp
        fields=('email','name')
    def clean_name(self):

        name=self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        if len(name) <=8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("name cannot be less than 8")
        return name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct name for your validation method. Django forms will call methods with the format `clean_<fieldname>`.

Also you seem to be confused about which field you are validating; your email validation method should be called `clean_email` and should access the email value via `form.cleaned_data['email']`, and the name one should be called `clean_name` and access `form.cleaned_data['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may give you some guidance.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    firstname = forms.CharField(label="First Name")
    lastname = forms.CharField(label="Last Name")
    phone = forms.CharField(label="Phone")
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password (again)")
    min_password_length = 8

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'phone', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email "%s" is already in use! Please log in or use another email!' % email)
    return email

def clean_password1(self):
    " Minimum length "
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1', '')
    if len(password1) < self.min_password_length:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password must have at least %i characters" % self.min_password_length)
    else:
        return password1

def clean(self):
    """
    Verifies that the values entered into the password fields match

    NOTE: Errors here will appear in ``non_field_errors()`` because it applies to more than one field.
    """
    cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords didn't match. Please try again.")
    return self.cleaned_data

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```